# Is it possible to build a Go library rather than a binary using Bazel?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, bazel

I have an application, that implements GRPC API. Bazel generates Go code using .proto files in the repository then builds a binary file.

My question: is it possible to configure a new target, so that Bazel would produce (in addition to the binary) a Go library other applications can use ?

I know that Bazel stores generated code somewhere deep within its sandbox, however I hope for a more reliable way, since the path may change in future Bazel releases.

UPD: in case it is not possible with Bazel, would appreciate any hints on how to achieve the same goal with different tools.

Comment: why not just use protogen?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not an option, since it involves using a messy shell script and a lot of trouble controlling versions of protobuf compilers.

Comment: "A Go library other applications can use" is just a code repository somewhere where `go get` can download it. I doesn't make sense to me to do this with Bazel. Either the code is generated on-demand to get reproducible builds based on the proto definitions, or you can just create a repository as usual and generate the code independent of Bazel to get reproducible builds based on the generated Go code. The latter is very common; whenever the proto files change generate all the library code in whatever languages you wish to support and publish everything together.

Comment: @Peter, thanks, you are perfectly reasonable. However, creating a separate repository means I have to configure some other tool to generate go code from proto files and somehow make  sure the same version of the protobuf compiler is used every time, so I was hoping Bazel could help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`go_proto_library`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/proto/core.rst#go_proto_library)

something like

```
go_proto_library(
    name = "date_go_proto",
    importpath = "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/type/date",
    protos = [":date_proto"],
)
```

this example is from [this file](https://github.com/olavloite/spannerclient/blob/1ce4fe7a7c535b62f1f9c1a8185f8f875fd69b06/src/main/protos/google/type/BUILD.bazel)

But if you are looking for something that generates source files instead of a binary compiled library checkout the ticket in [rules_go#512](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/512), there is work going on exactly this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I know, go_proto_library allows compiling a library, that can be used in subsequent build process as dependency, however  I do not know of a reliable way to access it afterwards. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Bazel is a build system after all, but this issue has some kinda long history, and maybe close to a solution, please checkout [rules_go#512](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/512)

Comment: Could you please add this link to your main answer, so I can mark it as accepted?